# Tableau Trial - no new custom SQL option

Tags: import, connection, tableau-api

I am fairly new to Tableau and just downloaded the Tableau trial version - I also imported an Excel doc and wanted to use SQL to manipulate the imported dataset - however I am not seeing the custom SQL option as advertised. Do I need a Database connection before I can write a SQL in Tableau or could the imported Excel be enough?

And if the database connection is required - I'd appreciate advice/links on how creating one

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server **and** PostgreSQL, please only tag a single RDBMS, and in this case, maybe none... I don't think they are directly related to Tableau.

Comment: I've removed both as the question doesn't appear to relate to either. If the question does relate to a specific RDBMS, then it needs to be updated to explain why.

Comment: Excel isn't a database. So why would you expect custom SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Install Tableau Prep - it allows to load an Excel doc to a table and yes, we need a Database connection.
You could then access this table from Tableau Desktop for building reports.
The Custom SQL option would work with  a database connection.